# Return array with nested array where query matches multiple elements

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this type of problem with this collection in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("585fe33d3c63b4a81e00002b"),
    "class" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "class 1",
            "people" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : "58596",
                    "name" : "mark",
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "45643",
                    "name" : "Susan",
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "85952",
                    "name" : "Loris",
                }
        },      
        {
            "name" : "class 2",
            "people" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : "58456",
                    "name" : "Sissi",
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "45643",
                    "name" : "Susan",
                }
            ]       
        }
    ]
}
```

and I have this type of array, ["Loris", "Susan"].

I would like to know which class has both names.

I know that it's easy but I really don't know what could be the right query in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `$in` with regex?
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in

```
{"class.people.name": {$in: [/Loris/, /Susan/]}}
```

Comment: could you tell me how can i take the name. 
Like have a variable in php with the value "class 1"?

Comment: The first comment in http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php shows an example of this.